# Add floats in Lyx without overlapping with other data

Tags: floats, lyx

I am trying to add figures and tables in Lyx. But, figures and tables overlap with other textual data. Below I have added images of the problem. Could someone help to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide a complete minimal example? Please see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: It's hard to tell because there's no example, but i think i can guess... by the looks of it you're working on a multi column document, adding the float on one column but it goes over the second ? If that is the case you need to enter the floats settings and select "span columns".

Comment: Thanks to both!! Yes @EladDen , this was precisely the problem.

Comment: Glad the problem was fixed. @EladDen please make your comment an answer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

While using a two column document, you are adding a float that goes over both columns.

Simply go into the floats options and tuck the "span columns"option. This turn the float to a `\figure*` or`\table*`.